# Android Uses-Feature VS. Uses-Permision Optimization

Tags: android, permissions, manifest, android-permissions

I have the following permissions explicitly requested in my manifest.

I would like to optimize store visibility by switching as many as possible of them to implicit 'uses-feature' declarations. I will also handle this additionally in code checking for features before I access them.

Internet access is the only thing that's truly required for my app, other features I can enable/disable conditionally based on hasFeatures().

Question: 
Which of these permissions can I change?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<permission android:name="com.appName.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.appName.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"  />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: "I would like to optimize store visibility by switching as many as possible of them to implicit 'uses-feature' declarations" -- there is no such concept. For example, even if you have `<uses-feature>` for location data, if you do not have the corresponding permission, you will be unable to get location data.

Comment: Not so true in case of camera! I can run an app that uses camera as a feature instead of a permission. Infect when I had a permission as well as feature my app was incompatible with Nexus tablet

Answer (score 0):

Set required to 'false' if your app doesn't require something to run:

> To control filtering, always explicitly declare hardware features in
>    elements, rather than relying on Google Play to
>   "discover" the requirements in  elements. Then, if
>   you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a
>   android:required="false" attribute to the  declaration.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html (in the right-hand sidebar)

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#declared) has this example:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```